# why the type of obj.i and std::forward<int>(obj.i) are different?

Tags: c++11

According to [Is a member of an rvalue structure an rvalue or lvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220230/is-a-member-of-an-rvalue-structure-an-rvalue-or-lvalue/2221470#2221470):

if `E1` is lvalue, then `E1.E2` is lvalue, and forward cast its argument to an rvalue only if that argument is bound to an rvalue. In function `void foo(Obj &&obj)` below, `obj` is lvalue, so `obj.i` is lvalue, why is `std::forward<int>(obj.i)` an rvalue?

```
class Obj
{
    public:
        int i;
};


void foo(int &i)
{
    cout<<"foo(int&)"<<endl;
}

void foo(int &&i)
{
    cout<<"foo(int&&)"<<endl;
}

void foo(Obj &&obj)
{
    foo(std::forward<int>(obj.i));
    foo(obj.i);
}

int main()
{
    Obj obj;
    foo(std::move(obj));
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
foo(int&&)
foo(int&)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually forwarding the wrong thing. In this function:

```
void foo(Obj &&obj)
{
    foo(std::forward<int>(obj.i));
    foo(obj.i);
}
```

`obj` has name, so it's an lvalue. `obj.i` is an lvalue in both cases, just in the first you're explicitly casting it to an rvalue! When `forward` gets a reference type, you get out an lvalue. When it gets a non-reference type, you get an rvalue. You're giving it a non-reference type, so the `forward` here is equivalent to: `foo(std::move(obj.i));` Does that make it clearer why you get an rvalue?

The question you linked, however, is about members of *rvalues*. To get that, you need to turn `obj` itself into an rvalue:

```
foo(std::move(obj).i);
```

Here, since `std::move(obj)` is an rvalue, `std::move(obj).i` is an rvalue as well.

---

Regardless, using `forward` when taking an argument by not-forwarding-reference is a little weird. Here's a more general example:

```
template <class O>
void foo(O&& obj) {
    foo(std::forward<O>(obj).i);
}

foo(obj);            // calls foo(int&)
foo(std::move(obj)); // calls foo(int&&)
```

In the former case, `std::forward<O>(obj)` is an lvalue because `O` is `Obj&`, which makes `std::foward<O>(obj).i` an lvalue. In the latter case, they're both rvalues.

Answer (score 0):

> function void foo(Obj &&obj) below:
>
> obj is lvalue, so obj.i is lvalue,

Hmm, do you declare `obj` as **rvalue reference** in function proto and then insist it's an **lvalue**?

Answer (score 0):

According to the specifications of `std::forward`, the return type is simple an rvalue reference applied to the template type. So the return type `std::forward<int>` is `int&&` - used in this way it has exactly the same effect as `std::move`.

The normal recipe for using `std::forward` is with universal references:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& val)
{
     other_func(std::forward<T>(val));
}
```

This would work correctly for references, as the deduced type for an lvalue reference in this case would also be an lvalue reference. In your case you're hard-coding the type (to `int`) rather than deducing it - the deduced type if you used the above pattern would in fact be `int&`, not `int`.

You will see that if you change `foo(std::forward<int>(obj.i))` to `foo(std::forward<int&>(obj.i))` you will get what you expect