# Returning a member from an rvalue object

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue

Lets take two structs/classes

```
struct C1{
  C1(){};
  C1(C1&){std::cout<<"copy"<<std::endl;}
  C1(C1&&){std::cout<<"move"<<std::endl;}};

struct C2{
  C1 c;
  C2(){};
  C1 get1(){return c;}
  C1 get2(){return std::move(c);}};
```

And than

```
C1 a1=C2().c;
C1 a2=C2().get1();
C1 a3=C2().get2();
```

the output is

```
move
copy
move
```

#### Question

We know that members of rvalues are rvalues themselves. This is why with a1, the move constructor is called. Why than, is the copy constructor called in the case of a2. We are returning an rvalue from a function.

To put it differently, std::move casts to an rvalue. But, as a member of an rvalue, c, is already an rvalue. Why than is there a difference between the behavior with a2 and a3?

Comment: Your copy-constructor is not callable with rvalues at all. Whenever you see it called, it is not to copy an rvalue, but for some other reason.

Answer (score 7):

Good question. The dull answer is that there's just no no rule in the C++ spec that says that returning a member from a dying object like this automatically moves it.

You may be interested in what's called *rvalue reference to this*. It let's you overload on `&&` and `&` such that you can manually implement the behaviour you expected:

```
struct C2{
  C1 c;
  C2(){};
  C1 get1() & { std::cout << "&" << std::endl; return c;}
  C1 get1() && { std::cout << "&&" << std::endl; return std::move(c);}
  C1 get2(){return std::move(c);}
};
```

Now

```
C1 a2=C2().get1();
```

prints

```
&&
move
```

Cool, but quite rare.

Related:

- [What is "rvalue reference for *this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this)
- [Is a member of an rvalue structure an rvalue or lvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220230/is-a-member-of-an-rvalue-structure-an-rvalue-or-lvalue)

Comment: Perhaps there should be such a rule. Time to write a standards proposal?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has put me at ease. I thought that I had missed something crucial, but it was just a missing rule, as you stated. I know about the possibility of the overload, I simply tried to provide the smallest example of the behavior; rvalue (member of an rvalue) being returned by a copy. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

> We know that members of rvalues are rvalues themselves.

Yes this is true, as states [[expr.ref]/4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#4.2) (emphasis mine):

> If E2 is a non-static data member and the type of E1 is “cq1 vq1 X”, and the type of E2 is “cq2 vq2 T”, the expression designates the named member of the object designated by the first expression. **If E1 is an lvalue, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; otherwise E1.E2 is an xvalue.** Let the notation vq12 stand for the “union” of vq1 and vq2; that is, if vq1 or vq2 is volatile, then vq12 is volatile. Similarly, let the notation cq12 stand for the “union” of cq1 and cq2; that is, if cq1 or cq2 is const, then cq12 is const. If E2 is declared to be a mutable member, then the type of E1.E2 is “vq12 T”. If E2 is not declared to be a mutable member, then the type of E1.E2 is “cq12 vq12 T”.

And also, from [[expr.ref]/4.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#4.5):

> If E2 is a member enumerator and the type of E2 is T, the expression E1.E2 is a prvalue. The type of E1.E2 is T.

So far so good. You can only get an lvalue if `E1` is an lvalue itself, otherwise it's an xvalue or a prvalue.

> But, as a member of an rvalue, c, is already an rvalue.

This is where your assumptions are wrong.

From [[class.this]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.this#1) (emphasis mine)

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value
>   is the address of the object for which the function is called. **The type of this in a member function of
>   a class X is X***.

`this` is a prvalue of type `X*`, and dereferencing a pointer of type `X` yield an lvalue of type `X`.

Since accessing a member inside a member function is equivalent to `(*this).m`, then `m` is accessed through an lvalue of type `X`.

So your code is equivalent to:

```
C1 get1() { return (*this).c; }
//      lvalue ----^       ^--- must be an lvalue too then.
```

Since `this` is always the same type, then even when using a function ref-qualifier the expression `c` inside a member function will always be an lvalue:

```
C1 get1() && { return (*this).c; }
//                            ^---- lvalue again, accessing through a pointer
```

Comment: I'm in an ongoing discussion elsewhere about this but you may want to mention `std::move(*this)`. If `*this` is `C2 &`, `std::move(*this)` is `C2 &&`, and finally `std::move(*this).c` is `C1 &&` by the same logic as for lvalues. At that point `C1::C1(C1&&)` is automatic, although, as a novice I would lean toward returning `C1 &&` so I could keep bumping the rvalue around unless I needed a permanent `C1`. That way it's still possible that some or all of the `C1` will end up getting discarded. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JohnP I don't think returning an rvalue reference from a rvalue-ref qualified member function is a bad idea, you just have to take that into account in your design and mitigate potential pitfalls.