# Three "const"s in const func (const scalar& a) const, why?

Tags: c++

newbie here!

I am reading a code and I see the author frequently writing a member function as

```
const int func (const scalar& a) const
// etc
```

You see there are three const here, now I understand the middle one, const scalar& a, that aims to not change the object a, but what about the other two const?

Is it a good habit that I should do this all the time, to protect blahblah unchanged?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is the return type? Is this in a class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you posted is not valid, it will not compile. However, if you consider

```
class MyClass {
  const int& func (const scalar& a) const {
    // ...
  }
};
```

The first `const` will specify that the return value is constant (i.e. immutable). The second `const` (`const scalar& a`) specifies that the function does not modify the value of the value of the argument `a`. The third const specifies that `func` is a constant member function, i.e. it does not modify the `MyClass` instance itself.

Comment: The key takeaway here is that each `const` is modifying a different part of the declaration, and each has a purpose.

Comment: Here's more fun!  `constexpr const char* const& func(const char* const& a) const`

Comment: `constexpr const char* const& func(const char* const& a) const`, what?

Comment: @Daniel That one is basically the same explanation except with `char* const` instead of `int` for the type and the C++11 `constexpr` keyword to also guarantee to the compiler that function is a compile-time constant ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has mentioned it yet: there is absolutely no difference between

```
const int some_function();
```

and

```
int some_function();
```

The `const` on scalar return types (such as `int`) is ignored; it only matters for class types. [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169932/)